# Filter an observable depending on id

Tags: angular, filter, observable

I'm trying to understand and work with **Observables**, I got it to work but now I need to filter the datas inside depending on the `id` they have, for example : datas that have `l1: 1` and `l2 : 2` should be grouped together just as datas that have
 `l1: 1,l2: 3,l3: 4`

[image]

Which approach is the best ? I tried with `.filter()` and `.distinct()` but can't get it to work, should I filter inside the component or directly inside the service ?

**service.ts**

```
  getStructure(): Observable<StructureInterface[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<StructureInterface[]>(`someUrl`)
      .pipe(
        tap(data =>
        console.log('Get structure done ', data)),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
```

**interface.ts**

```
export interface StructureInterface {
  parts: {
    part: string,
    l1: number,
    l2: number,
    l3: number,
    diam: Array<{}>;
    price1: number,
    price2: number
  },
  labels_levels: [string];
  labels_diameters: [string];
}
```

**component.ts**

```
  labels: any[];


  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient,
              private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
              private service: Service
              ) {
  }


//Call to service

  ngOnInit() {
      this.service.getStructure().subscribe(
        res => {
          this.labels = res;
          //I tried .filter() here
          console.log(this.labels)
        });

  }
```

Thank's for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about the data flow here:

1. Incoming http response - unfiltered array of stuff
2. Piped through one-time observable http.get()
3. Returned to your component as an array of StructureInterface objects

I think you want to filter the data at step 3, which means this is a concern after the observable has completed, so it is just a straight up array filter. How you filter the array depends on what data you need.

This example would only keep objects where l1 is equal to 1:

```
this.service.getStructure().subscribe(res => {
  this.labels = res.filter(structure => structure.l1 === 1);
  // will only include array items with an l1 value of 1
  console.log(this.labels)
});
```

EDIT
To answer your question about where you should filter, it depends on your use case. Ideally you would pass your id parameter(s) to the server and filter there. If you cannot control that, then you could apply the filter inside an observable map():

```
getStructure(l1: number): Observable<StructureInterface[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<StructureInterface[]>(`someUrl`)
      .pipe(
        map(response => response.parts.filter(x => x.l1 === l1)),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. That's a really clear and helpfull answer. The thing I don't understand is that I'm getting this error ``ERROR TypeError: res.filter is not a function``, same one as when I tried to use ``.filter()`` by myself

Comment: That means it isn't an array. Looking at your question, it should be res.parts.filter()